# Polymer key global variables undefined. Why?

Tags: polymer

I've got a strange set of errors as I load up my application

```
polymer-micro.html:117 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_makeReady' of undefined
     (anonymous function) @ polymer-micro.html:117
```

The indefined in this first one is `Polymer.RenderStatus`

```
polymer.html:3417 Uncaught TypeError: Polymer.dom is not a function
     _findStyleHost @ polymer.html:3417
     _computeStyleProperties @ polymer.html:3461
     _applyCustomProperties @ polymer.html:3652
     fn @ polymer.html:3638
```

Obviously Polymer.dom ought to be a function.  why is it not?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_isEventBogus' of undefined
      _notifyListener @ polymer.html:2012
      (anonymous function) @ polymer.html:1534
      fire @ polymer.html:1277
      _notifyChange @ polymer.html:1372
      _notifyEffect @ polymer.html:1553
     _effectEffects @ polymer.html:1405
     _propertySetter @ polymer.html:1389
     setter @ polymer.html:1468q
     ueryHandler @ iron-media-query.html:116
```

This is a media query that generates this error everytime we move the width of the screen across the media query boundary.  The undefined variable in this case is `Polymer.Bind`

If I put a breakpoint at the top of polymer.html (just after the script tag) The errors go away when I then let it go.  This almost implies that normally it is running without letting polymer-mini.html load.

I am running with chrome, and the tests in index.html as to whether to load the `webcomponents-lite.js` polyfill means it doesn't load.

I am stuck about what to do about debugging this issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: Adam's edit fixed the formatting. There is no need to revert it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the positioning of the initialisation script in index.html is the cause of these problems.  I had copied the Polymer Shop app which places the script at the bottom of the body.  The app created by the polymer-cli tool (with the app-drawer template) places the script in the header, before importing the my-app element.

I suspect the reason the shop app doesn't have problems is the header is not doing any animation.  I am using a blend-background effect in my header and that might be why it fails.

Anyway, moving the script which includes the Polymer initialization into the header solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Adding async to the import solved it for me.

```
<link rel="import" href="/src/your-app.html" async>
```

Instead of

```
<link rel="import" href="/src/your-app.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm experimenting with the 2.0 preview and had a similar set of errors trying to follow Rob Dodson's routing Polycast (#47, 48 ish).  This is what worked after many hours of trying other solutions:

```
    **<script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">**
  // Setup Polymer options
  window.Polymer = {
    dom: 'shadow',
    lazyRegister: true
  };

  // Load webcomponentsjs polyfill if browser does not support native Web Components
  (function() {
    'use strict';

    var onload = function() {
      // For native Imports, manually fire WebComponentsReady so user code
      // can use the same code path for native and polyfill'd imports.
      if (!window.HTMLImports) {
        document.dispatchEvent(
          new CustomEvent('WebComponentsReady', {bubbles: true})
        );
      }
    };

    var webComponentsSupported = (
      'registerElement' in document
      && 'import' in document.createElement('link')
      && 'content' in document.createElement('template')
    );

    if (!webComponentsSupported) {
      **// var script = document.createElement('script');
      // script.async = true;
      // script.src = '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js';
      // script.onload = onload;
      // document.head.appendChild(script);**
    } else {
      onload();
    }
  })();

  // Load pre-caching Service Worker
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
    });
  }
</script>
```